# Postgres unique combination constraint across tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have three tables -

```
file (
  file_id int primary key
  filename text not null
  etc...
)
product (
  product_id int primary key
  etc....
)
product_attachment (
  product_id references product
  file_id references file
)
```

I want to ensure that when these are natural-joined, product_id + filename is unique.
The best solution I have so far involves adding filename to the product_attachment table, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the filename column is not unique you can add a custom constraint on your `product_attachment` table. Note that this will execute the query below on every insert and update, which is not ideal performance wise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_filename(product_id integer, file_id integer)
RETURNS boolean AS
$$
    LOCK product_attachment IN SHARE MODE;
    SELECT (COUNT(*) = 0)
    FROM product_attachment pa
    JOIN file f1 ON f1.file_id = pa.file_id
    JOIN file f2 ON f1.filename = f2.filename
    WHERE pa.product_id = $1 AND f2.file_id = $2
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

ALTER TABLE product_attachment
ADD CONSTRAINT check_filename CHECK
(check_filename(product_id, file_id))
```

Comment: I'm not clear why you have a "for update" there, and I think the test should be count(*) = 0 (or using a sub-query with "exists" might yield better performance), but this is exactly the approach I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @qcodepeter you're right, it should be `count(*) = 0`, `for update` locks the selected rows in order to prevent a race condition

Comment: If I understand correctly, the query will either lock and return 0 rows - in which case the lock does nothing - or the constraint will fail - in which case the lock does nothing. Maybe adding a "lock product_attachment in share mode" to the start of the query will do the trick?

Comment: @qcodepeter if i understood [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html), `for update` acquires a table level lock but it's probably clearer and safer to explicitly lock the table as you've mentioned. btw if it's possible to update `filename` you may need a similar constraint on your `file` table

Comment: you're right to say that it acquires a table level lock, but it's only a `row share` lock, which I don't think will be enough. As it happens, we aren't currently allowing `filename` updates, so I'm not going to worry about that, but yes, that would otherwise be a consideration.

Comment: CHECK constraints are just for the local tuple data and should not reference other tables. The documentation is quite explicit about this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html. We did that once and the result was that a db dump could not be loaded without errors. Something about the assumptions of the order of initialization of tables, constraints and functions - I don't remember exactly. We had to change it in the end.

Comment: You could use a constraint trigger, not a CHECK constraint, for the above suggested solution and defer it until the end of the transaction. This could be a good enough solution, but it still doesn't guarantee uniqueness as there is a window after the function runs and before the transaction commits that the constraint could be violated in concurrent scenarios. Otherwise, creating another table with the the relevant columns populated through triggers one the current tables, along with a unique index is probably the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a unique constraint to `product_attachment`?

```
create unique index idx_product_attachment_2 on product_attachment(product_id, file_id);
```

This assumes that the file name is unique, which you can ensure by defining the file name to be unique in that table.

Comment: File name is not unique across the entire file table, unfortunately that's a requirement of the system.