# postgresql: constaint to have unique values across 2 tables

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public."user"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
    username character varying(256) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.user_tenant
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    tenant_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I need to have unique values (user.username, user_tenant.tenant_id). How can I declare such a constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the username unique, just like the tenant that is in another table. When that is done, you can put a primary key on the user_id and tenant_id:

```
CREATE TABLE public."user"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
    username character varying(256) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" unique,
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.user_tenant
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    tenant_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT user_tenant_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id, tenant_id)
);
```

By the way, don't use reserved names like "user" for table names.

Comment: thank you.. But I need to have possibility to put not unique `username`, example: `Frank Heikens`. But those Franks should belong to different tenants.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which can check for uniqueness across multiple tables (example here: [Postgres unique combination constraint across tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910113/postgres-unique-combination-constraint-across-tables)) but it looks like you may need to the structure of your tables or follow Frank Heikens' answer.

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE public."user"
(
    id       SERIAL,
    username character varying(256) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.user_tenant
(
    user_id   integer NOT NULL,
    tenant_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.check_user_tenant(user_id integer, tenant_id integer)
    RETURNS boolean AS
$$
    DECLARE b_result boolean;
BEGIN
    SELECT (COUNT(*) = 0) INTO b_result
    FROM public.user u
             JOIN public.user_tenant ut ON ut.user_id IN (SELECT id
                                                          FROM public.user i_u
                                                          WHERE i_u.username = u.username)
    WHERE u.id = $1 AND ut.tenant_id = $2;
    RETURN b_result;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

ALTER TABLE public.user_tenant
ADD CONSTRAINT check_filename CHECK
(public.check_user_tenant(user_id, tenant_id));

-- Testing:
insert into public."user" (username) VALUES ('foo');
insert into public.user_tenant (user_id, tenant_id) VALUES (1,3);

insert into public."user" (username) VALUES ('foo');
-- Violates constraint:
insert into public.user_tenant (user_id, tenant_id) VALUES (2,3);
```

Comment: I know I can use triggers and prevent inserting/modifying data if it is not valid. But I;d prefer to add constraints to tables schema.

Comment: OK, so I would say you can use the example in this answer to create a function and then use that as a check constraint. I'll edit the answer and provide the SQL. It's a bit clunky and you will probably need an index on user.username, but it works.